# Правильно ли построена речь, и можно ли сказать лучше?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли построена речь, и можно ли сказать лучше? "При обычном построении подлежащее ставится в начале предложения,затем идет сказуемое,и этот порядок нарушается только при инверсии,которая не является примером правильного построения членов предложения".

Comment: Во-первых, Вы должны сказать правильно не только  форме, но и по сути. Из Ваших слов следует, что инверсия - это неправильно. Инверсия - это нарушение прямого порядка слов. Это может быть ошибкой, а может быть средством выразительности. Не скажете же Вы, что "Жили-были дед да баба" - неправильно, и надо изменить на "дед да баба жили-были". Чтобы править Вашу речь, нужно знать, что именно Вы хотите сказать, кому, в какой ситуации.

Comment: Большое спасибо!!! А можно сказать?" "При обычном построении подлежащее ставится в начале предложения,затем идет сказуемое,и этот порядок нарушается только при инверсии,которая не является примером прямого построения членов предложения".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"При обычном построении подлежащее ставится в начале предложения,затем идет сказуемое,и этот порядок нарушается только при инверсии,которая не является примером правильного построения членов предложения".-есть недочёты, особенно во второй части.Правильное построение ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ, а не членов предложения, они не строятся. Лучше сказать:

Обычно подлежащее в повествовательном предложении стоит впереди сказуемого - это прямой порядок слов.Обратный порядок (инверсия)является отступлением от обычного и создаёт добавочные смысловые оттенки.

Кроме того,порядок указывает на синтаксическую функцию частей речи:слово в ПРЕпозиции обычно является подлежащим и имеет соответствующие грамматические признаки, слово в ПОСТпозиции -сказуемым со своими признаками, что важно в предложениях - тождествах типа Мать любит дочь.

"подлежащее в своей основе" - лексически неверно, у подлежащего нет основы.Можно сказать "правило в своей основе", а подлежащее - нет. Вместо этого выражения подойдёт "обычно", "как норма", "в основном".

Comment: Может быть, так: В русском языке порядок слов свободный, в арабском – фиксированный. Для именного предложения в арабском языке характерен прямой порядок (подлежащее – сказуемое); В глагольном предложении порядок главных членов «сказуемое – подлежащее – дополнение». Глагольному сказуемому может предшествовать обстоятельство;подлежащее и прямое дополнение могут отсутствовать.Переводя арабское предложение, нужно смотреть на контекст – нейтральное это предложение (простая констатация факта)или какое-то слово в нём подчёркивается, выделяется, что в свою очередь не меняет порядка слов при переводе.

Comment: дело не в этом, можно сказать:Студент в университете.Можно сказать:В университете студент. И в первом и во втором предложении подлежащее слово "студент" И в первом и во втором предложении управляющим фактором,который влияет на окончание является смысловым (постановка подлежащего в начале предложения).Что касается первого предложения, здесь вопросов нет ,что касается второго,нужно объяснить ,что в нем,  несмотря на инверсию, в арабском считается,что управляющим фактором,который влияет на окончание тот же самый

Comment: (постановка подлежащего в начале предложения)подлежащее(в основе)стоит в начале,как это сказать правильно по- русски.

Comment: В арабском языке на окончание существительного-объекта влияет главенствующее положение подлежащего-субъекта независимо от его позиции.
ИЛИ: Препозиция (как правило)подлежащего влияет на окончание ...
ИЛИ:Постановка подлежащего в начало(как правило) предложения влияет...
ИЛИ: Подлежащее обычно(за исключением инверсии)занимает первую позицию в предложении и оказывает влияние на окончание сущ.-объекта.

Comment: Тогда так: Начальное положение подлежащего-субъекта требует окончания им.падежа даже при инверсии.

Comment: "в основе оно даже при инверсии остается в начале " действительно не по-русски звучит, противоречиво.А если так: Начальное положение подлежащего-субъекта требует окончания им.падежа даже при инверсии, ведь смысловой приоритет остаётся за подлежащим.

Answer (score 2):

Грамматическая основа двухсоставных предложений состоит из подлежащего и сказуемого, причем подлежащее обычно предшествует сказуемому.

В некоторых случаях возможно изменение такого порядка слов (инверсия), что связано с решением различных задач, например необходимостью логического выделения сказуемого: "Роняет лес багряный свой убор, Сребрит мороз увянувшее поле, Проглянет день как будто поневоле И скроется за край окружных гор".

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!А можно сказать?" "При обычном построении подлежащее ставится в начале предложения,затем идет сказуемое,и этот порядок нарушается только при инверсии,которая не является примером прямого построения членов предложения"

Comment: В вашем варианте встречается много выражений терминологического характера,которые не являются общепринятыми и даже не совсем понятны и точны, например: "обычное построение","нарушение порядка", "прямое построение членов предложения". Даже термин "построение предложения" мне не очень ясен, обычно говорят о структуре предложения.В своем ответе я привела пример возможного изложения этого материала, хотя, конечно, надо учитывать аудиторию, для которой создается текст. Если это младшие школьники,то можно упростить выражения - например, не "предшествует сказуемому", а "стоит перед сказуемым" и т.д.

Comment: Большое спасибо,София!!! Речь идет о подлежащем.О том, что его основное место это начало предложения (в иностранном языке).
Но как и в русском языке есть инверсия и члены предложения меняются местами. Можно ли сказать? "Подлежащее в своей основе ставится в начале предложения ,хотя  при инверсии прямой порядок нарушается , подлежащее и сказуемое меняются местами,тогда как при прямом построении сначала ставится подлежащее затем сказуемое".Как выглядит выражение"Подлежащее в своей основе ставится в начале предложения? Правильно ли это звучит?

Comment: Если это английская грамматика, то там, конечно, другая терминология. Есть прямой порядок слов, есть инверсия, то есть обратный порядок. Я думаю, вам лучше составить ваш текст по какому-нибудь образцу. Например, откройте в поисковике "прямой и обратный порядок слов" и используйте любое стандартное описание, немного откорректировав его под ваши нужды. В этом случае составлять свое собственное описание - дело неблагодарное, в любом выражении можно допустить неточность.

Comment: Спасибо! Язык арабский .В арабском язык "падеж" зависит от управляющих факторов, влияющих на окончания ,которые бывают либо смысловыми,либо словесными,все арабисты не объясняют эту тему,а просто сравнивают с русским языком.Но если не знать об управляющих факторах,освоить грамматику арабского почти невозможно...

Comment: Нужно объяснить ,что фактор подлежащего является смысловым, а не словесным.То есть фактором ,который влияет на окончание, является  постановка подлежащего в начале предложения,но  у изучающих может возникнуть вопрос "Как его фактором может быть постановка в начале предложения,если подлежащие иногда стоит после сказуемого.Можно рассказать про инверсию и сказать ,что подлежащее в своей основе всегда стоит на первом месте,но не знаю правильно ли  звучит выражение "подлежащее в своей основе" по- русски?

Comment: Может быть, Вас устроит такой вариант:При прямом построении подлежащее находится в начале предложения и  далее следует сказуемое, но при инверсии прямой порядок слов нарушается и сказуемое ставится перед подлежащим.